# Using PHP inside jQuery and if/else statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 5 circles that appear inside a div which change depending on the accuracy of a certain thing.

For example <20 accuracy is only 1 filled (red) circle, with 4 unfilled circles.

**Visual: This is 60-80 accuracy** http://puu.sh/hnJsR/20af976827.png

The below code is inside:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

The code:

```
var accuracy1 = <?php echo 100*(1-$s1/1.33333); ?>;
var accuracy2 = <?php echo 100*(1-$s2/1.33333); ?>;

if (accuracy1 < 20) {
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle1"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
}
elseif(accuracy1 >= 20 && accuracy1 < 40) {
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle2"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle2"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
}
elseif(accuracy1 >= 40 && accuracy1 < 60) {
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle3"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle3"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle3"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
}
elseif(accuracy1 >= 60 && accuracy1 < 80) {
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle4"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle4"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle4"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle4"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircleunfilled"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
}
else {
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle5"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle5"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle5"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle5"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
        $('<div class="accuracycircle accuracycircle5"></div>').appendTo('#circlesdiv1');
}
```

$s1 and $s2 are numbers declared earlier in a PHP tag that I transform to make it an accuracy between 0 and 100.

It doesn't work and is obviously very messy. What am I doing wrong and how could I clean it up too?

Comment: try put quote `var accuracy1 = '<?php echo 100*(1-$s1/1.33333); ?>;'`

Comment: did you know about `switch`?

Comment: Why on earth would he make a number used as a number a string?
elseif is not JavaScript syntax by the way. try `else if`

Comment: put the accuracy  in a hidden input use js's 'switch` to change the div, and why do you repeat yourself?

Comment: I'd like to see the code if there were 100 circles to display :)

Comment: ah else if works, woops. Although it came up with this: http://puu.sh/hnJZf/539f171ef2.png - the accuracy was 70%

Comment: Woops the first 5 circles are static, I forgot to remove them. But there's 2 extra circles on the end.

Comment: Much better done with a for loop, will write a jsfiddle in a sec

Comment: @DBrown2207 Check out my answer. Much clean and without for loop.

Comment: @Tushar, yeah looks good, didn't know about repeat function :), mine works the same but less compact http://jsfiddle.net/zhe3m4sw/ was gonna add in the ciel stuff later but yours already has it in

Comment: @frosty Checkout updated answer. Much Cleaner!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can clean your code.

1. Use repeater to repeat the string, instead of repeating the code
2. Use `:lt` selector to select all the elements having index less than the provided

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jz5w93qo/)

```js
// Repeat a string num times
String.prototype.repeat = function(num) {
  return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
};

var accuracy1 = 70; // Will be dynamic

var totalCircles = 5,
  noOfFilledCircles = Math.ceil(accuracy1 / 20);
noOfFilledCircles = noOfFilledCircles > 5 ? 5 : noOfFilledCircles;

var circleHtml = '<div class="accuracycircle"></div>';

$('#circlesdiv1').append(circleHtml.repeat(totalCircles)).find('div:lt(' + noOfFilledCircles + ')').addClass('accuracycircle1');
```

```css
div#circlesdiv1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3C3E46;
}
#circlesdiv1 .accuracycircle {
  background-color: #8A8A8A;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
div.accuracycircle1 {
  background-color: #DBFF94 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circlesdiv1"></div>
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using "accuracycircle " css class for unfilled and "accuracycircle accuracycircle-filled" css classes for filled circles. That way, it's easier to toggle filled/unfilled circle using jQuery and it's easier for a human to understand

Answer (score 0):

You really really want to stop repeating your code like this. Use loops and conditions to generate stuff. Imagine, you have 100 circles to display, will you repeat 100 lines of codes 100 times? Will you really copy-paste 10.000 lines of code? Besides, each `('#circlesdiv1')` is a call to the DOM, this needs to be done once and cached.

Here's a quick go at your problem, it's not perfect, but feel free to adapt it.

It's configurable, you can generate any number of circles you want as a scale, and it's just like 10 lines of code.

**@Future downvoters, at least PLEASE SAY WHY you downvote.**

```js
/*------ CONFIGURATION -----*/
var accuracy1 = 20
var maxCircles = 5
/* -------------------------*/


var $circlesdiv1 = $('#circlesdiv1')
var filledCircles = parseInt(accuracy1/(100/maxCircles))

// Building empty circles
for(i=0; i<maxCircles; i++)
 $circlesdiv1.append('<div class="accuracyCircle"></div>')

// Filling requested number of circles, adding classes
for(i=0; i<=filledCircles; i++)
 $circlesdiv1
  .find(".accuracyCircle:nth-child("+(i+1)+")")
  .addClass("filled accuracycircle"+(filledCircles+1))
```

```css
div#circlesdiv1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
div.accuracyCircle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #008000 solid 1px;
}
div.accuracyCircle.filled {
  background: #008000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circlesdiv1"></div>
```

Comment: You are using two `for` loops, not required at all

Comment: True, it can also be done with one. As I said, it's a quick go and it's not perfect. Two loops are maybe easier to understand.

Comment: easier to understand(?) and slower when there are 100s/1000s of circles